# PrestoSQL comma-delimited varchar column to JSON array

Tags: sql, json, presto

I have a column in a table extracted from json using `json_extract_scalar(json_parse(<my json array>), '$.column')`

Now I have a column in the table that is a varchar (I believe) and looks like:

| column |
| --- |
| word1, word2, word3, word4 |

I want to use this column later and put it in a nested JSON array, but if I put it into a json array as it is right now, it will look like:

`"column":"word1, word2, word3, word4"` in the json array, when I instead want:

`"column": ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]`

So, my question is how do I make the column into a JSON array/list first so that the output is what I want when I later put it in an array?

I have tried doing `CAST(column AS JSON)` but it gives me:

| column |
| --- |
| "word1, word2, word3, word4" |

I'm using Presto SQL

Answer (score 0):

`CAST(SPLIT(json_extract_scalar(json_parse(<my json array>), '$.column'), ',') AS JSON)` gave me the output I desired

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert you string into an array, for example using [`split`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#id1):

```sql
select cast(split('word1, word2, word3, word4', ',') as json)
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| ["word1"," word2"," word3"," word4"] |